# How do I implement a custom binding for Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Azure Functions come with a fixed set of pre-existing bindings.

At the same time, Azure Functions are based on Web Jobs SDK, which have some [extensibility story](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/). It enables creating custom binding types, including custom triggers.

Is it possible to run those custom bindings in Azure Function runtime? If yes, is there a tutorial or documentation on how to do that? If no, any plans to?

Some sample usage scenario would be integrating to non-Azure products (e.g. Kafka) or custom in-house protocols.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Custom input and output bindings are now fully supported. More information can be found on the Azure WebJobs wiki: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Creating-custom-input-and-output-bindings

> This wiki describes how to define a custom binding extension for the WebJobs SDK. These same extensions can be used, without modification, in Azure Functions.

A sample binding which writes to a Slack channel be found here: https://github.com/lindydonna/SlackOutputBinding

Comment: What about triggers? There is some form of custom trigger bindings, which is used by Durable Extensions and e.g. Event Grid binding.

Comment: @Mikhail Custom triggers are not officially supported yet for extensibility (there are a lot of difficulties in making something like that work well and support dynamic scale). Right now we are leaning towards asking folks to use Event Grid for custom triggers, and we're working on improving the Event Grid binding to help with that.

Comment: My theory was that one can create binding "derived" from standard, like Orchestration probably uses Storage Queue, and Event Grid is based on HTTP. This way one could get scalability backend from that binding, and just define more use-case specific semantics. Am I thinking it wrong?

Comment: @Mikhail It's possible we may do this internally for webhook triggers, but I don't believe we have derived trigger support anywhere else. We are looking at it as a possible new feature to improve the experience of certain trigger types (think Durable + HTTP), but we really don't have any official support for either custom or derived triggers at this point.

Comment: @ChrisGillum We use MassTransit (MT), an open source lib for building a service bus on Azure.  MT implements the concept of publishers and consumers.  Consumers essentially subscribe to events in the bus.  MT builds on top of transport layer (Azure Service Bus sdk) to handle the communication.  We'd love to be able to create Az Function and use a MT Service Bus Trigger.  Has anything changed in the roadmap for building custom triggers?

Answer (score 1):

We have a preview of 'Bring Your Own Binding' feature'. See [Extensibility](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Extensibility) for more details on the feature and [WebJobsExtensionSamples](https://github.com/Azure/WebJobsExtensionSamples) for sample and docs.
Also, you can track the feature [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/labels/feature%3Abyob)

Comment: What about custom trigger bindings?

Comment: Custom triggers are not currently supported and not part of the initial extensibility work. Triggers require additional platform integration to ensure the Function App is awaken as a result of an event, and that integration is not part of the current scope.

Comment: I somewhere read that for Custom Triggers, EventGrid would be used in the furture.

Comment: Only to confirm Fabio Cavalcante comment, when he answered @Mikhail
"This wiki focuses on how to define custom input and output bindings. Custom triggers are not available for Azure Functions." 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Creating-custom-input-and-output-bindings