# Azure Functions - Custom Trigger Binding MQTT

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I would need to create a trigger binding on an MQTT message from a broker outside of Azure.
Is there any documentation on how to create custom bindings for triggers?

Azure Functions V2 with C#
Thanks a lot

P.S. Work this example for my porpuse?
https://medium.com/@yuka1984/how-to-make-custom-trigger-with-azure-functions-3bd85551ac5e

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I implement a custom binding for Azure Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44478231/how-do-i-implement-a-custom-binding-for-azure-functions)

Comment: There's a NuGet package for that already... [CaseOnline.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Mqtt](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CaseOnline.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Mqtt/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @rickvdbosch, I will try it!

Comment: Make sure to run your Azure Function in App Service Plan. Custom triggers will only work (without being supported) in those, not in Consumption Plan.

Comment: Maybe it's better to decouple your MQTT traffic to Azure Service Bus or something similar first and than process it with Azure Functions (push to pull decoupling help you to gain more control over your workload)

Comment: @SebastianAchatz right solution is event grid. But our costumer wan't to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Custom triggers are not available for Azure Functions.

Source: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Creating-custom-input-and-output-bindings

You can actually write custom triggers, I did that a while ago based on [this](https://medium.com/@yuka1984/how-to-make-custom-trigger-with-azure-functions-3bd85551ac5e), but it's not supported. Especially since the whole scale out logic will not work.

Supported are only custom input and output bindings at this time.

Comment: Custom trigger is planning for next release? There is a roadmap?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot speak for the Functions team. Best would be to create an issue on their GitHub: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues